# How can i center amazon native shopping ads in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so im using amazon's native shopping ads however, it seems that they will not load if they are embedded into a Div and if you edit the ID in css to something like

```
#amazon-id-here {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

It just breaks and wont load, and I couldn't add a new class to it with these parameters either. Are they just not allowed to be edited? Thanks.

Comment: Can you update part of html and javascript to embed native shopping for more details? And are you using iframe to load amazon ads?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

A simpler solution seems to be wrapping the entire Amazon code between a CENTER tag. Example:

```html
<center><div id="amzn-assoc-ad-123456-4693-1213-8052-17231123"></div><script async src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=123456-4693-1213-8052-17231123"></script></center>
```

**OLD SOLUTION**

I came across the same issue, my first theory was that it looks like Amazon doesn't allow this practice, that's why the div becomes empty, but I guess it's just a problem about div sizing in their javascript code, resulting in 0 if we apply a margin: 0 auto before the div loads.

My workaround is to inject a jquery css edit after an interval, so you just need to replace the part "#your amazon div ID here" with your actual div id and you're done.

```
    <script>
        setInterval(amzfix,2000);
        function amzfix() {
            $("#your amazon div ID here").css("margin", "0 auto");
        }
    </script>
```